# How to update a view position

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a function which create buttons automatically from a list in a relative layout but the buttons position is not getting updated, I have to call a function later to get the new position

```
val ppl = mutableListOf("ppl 1", "ppl 2", "ppl 3", "ppl 4")
private const val TAG = "MyActivity"
fun getPos(view:View) {
    for (boutton in buttons){
        boutton.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        Log.i(TAG,"${boutton.text} - x: ${location[0]} y: ${location[1]}")
    }
}
fun initButton(view: View){

    var count = 1
    var lastID:Int = 0

    for (ppl in ppls){

        bouton = Button(this)
        bouton.id = View.generateViewId()
        params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        bouton.text = ppl
        if (count >= 3) {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, lastID)
            count = 0
        }
        else{
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastID)
            count++

        }
        conteneurPersonne.addView(bouton, params)
        lastID = bouton.id
        buttons.add(bouton)
        bouton.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        Log.i(TAG,"${bouton.text} - x: ${location[0]} y: ${location[1]}")
        }
     }
```

Logcat

Log from "initButton":

```
    I/MyActivity: ppl 1 - x: 28 y: 2139
    I/MyActivity: ppl 2 - x: 28 y: 2139
    I/MyActivity: ppl 3 - x: 28 y: 2139
    I/MyActivity: ppl 4 - x: 28 y: 2139
```

but if I execute "getPos":

```
    I/MyActivity: ppl 1 - x: 28 y: 2139
    I/MyActivity: ppl 2 - x: 28 y: 2307
    I/MyActivity: ppl 3 - x: 396 y: 2139
    I/MyActivity: ppl 4 - x: 28 y: 2307
```

[Consequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzbvJ.png)

"Ppl 4" is not below "Ppl 3" because buttons positions didn't get refreshed

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want that Log from "initButton" be the same as "getPos" I don't want to execute this function to get real position

Comment: Where are `initButton` and `getPos` called?

Comment: They are called when I click on a specifig Button https://imgur.com/a/5dTLVr5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "ppl 2" button is below your "ppl 4" button because of the way you've set up your params. Try the following and see if it generates the output you expect,

```java
fun initButton(view: View){

    var count = 1
    var lastID:Int = 0

    for (ppl in ppls){

        bouton = Button(this)
        bouton.id = View.generateViewId()
        params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        bouton.text = ppl
        /*
        //Instead of this
        if (count >= 3) {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, lastID)
            count = 0
        }
        else{
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastID)
            count++

        }
        */
        //Try the following
        if (count <= 2) {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastID)
        } else {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, buttons[buttons.size - 2].id)
            if (count%2 == 0) {
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastID)
            }
        }
        count++
        conteneurPersonne.addView(bouton, params)
        lastID = bouton.id
        buttons.add(bouton)
        bouton.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        Log.i(TAG,"${bouton.text} - x: ${location[0]} y: ${location[1]}")
        }
     }
}
```